# Boot Failure when loading Hyper-V VHD converted from VHDX

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, azure

I have Hyper-V 2nd generation Virtual Machine connected to VHDX drive with Windows 10 Enterprise on it.
I need to move this virtual machine to Azure. It will be used to spin-up developers Vm. Other developers will use it.

I have found this article :

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image

I run the `sfx.exe` command and also converted the VHDX drive to VHD using Hyper-V wizard.

VHD drive takes about 230 GB. Uploading it to Azure takes around 13 hours. This is why I wanted to check it first locally.

After converting to VHD there are some additional steps that I need to do in order to upload it to Azure.
Before I have uploaded it to the Azure I want to create new Virtual Machine using VHD locally. 
I have created 1st generation Virtual Machine. When I try to load it, I get :

```
Boot failure. Reboot and Select propert Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device
```

[image: Error message from Hyper-V]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You can't use a VHD with a Gen2 VM.  VHD is legacy.  Moving between Gen2 and Gen1 is not supported by MS.  You're better off creating a new Gen 1 VM.

Comment: You can automatically migrate VM to Azure with starwind v2v converter - https://www.starwindsoftware.com/v2v-help/VMfromMicrosoftHyperVServertoMicrosoftAzure.html